# How to privately host RPubs?

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudio has nice support for RMarkdown where any .rmd can be directly published to RPubs.
    http://rpubs.com/

Now, catch is that this is publicly hosted and any document published here will be visible to all.
Is it possible to host it privately or under some access control ?

Comment: The HTML created is static, so you could put it behind any web-server and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what RPubs would have solved for me (+ integration with RStudio)